# PFeast : what’s that token?

Tags: ether, erc-20

While everyone can create a token, [this one](https://etherscan.io/address/0xf8a4d3a0b5859a24cd1320ba014ab17f623612e2) seems to have attracted a lot of value from third party users (current ether balance place it in the top 500 and with more than 9000 users).

By disassembling the bytecode, it definitely seems not be a wallet contract… But does someone have more informations about the project ? I mean the source code or how to use the contract ?

Comment: You have some confusion in your terms. A wallet is not a contract (unless it's a multisig wallet where part of the functionality is in a contract) and definitely not a token. The address you gave is just some ERC20 token and this is not really the right place to ask for information about random ERC20 tokens.

Comment: @LauriPeltonen I was meaning a Wallet type of contract. With such value, it’s not so much a random token.